# Python3: ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, pymysql

Below code works perfectly in python2 with MySQLDB, how can I make it Python3 compatible?

I have debugged and searched for similar questions.

> Error:
>   Exception ignored in: > Traceback (most recent call last): File > > > "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 41, in del File > "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 47, in close ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists –

```
class Database():

    def __init__(self):
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.user = 'user'
        self.password = 'pwd'  
        self.db = 'dbname'
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(host=self.host, user=self.user, passwd=self.password, db=self.db,use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def storeToDB(self,ID,string,g,e):
        import datetime

        curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        status = 0
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO master_data (`job_id`,`sstring`,`grl`,`erl`,`status`,`insert_timestamp`) \
            VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(jobID,search_string,g,e,status,curr_time))
            self.connection.commit()
        except:
            self.connection.rollback()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = Database()
    db.storeToDB(20,"hello","something.com","e.com")
```

Comment: Your example code would not even compile. Please show the exact code, or obscure the local variables correctly.

Comment: but it's interpreted... :)

Comment: I suggest looking into something like ['2to3'](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)

Comment: Is that the full traceback? I assume some exception is triggered in your `try except` block. It's usually a bad idea to use a catch-all `except` and not reraise the error.

Comment: @HåkenLid updated full traceback in question

Comment: Your traceback doesn't seem to be triggered by anything in the code you posted.

Comment: @HåkenLid yes that's why its puzzling me and this happens specifically in python3 only, its inserting fine with py2

Comment: Well. Your code catches all exceptions and then ignores them. Check out how it's done in the pymysql's documentation instead. Use a context manager (`with connection.cursor() as cursor:`) and `try-finally` instead of `try-except-(pretend error didn't happen)`  http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid, running same code as given in example gives me this error with py3 but works fine with py2.

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "pymysqltest.py", line 12, in <module> with connection.cursor() as cursor: AttributeError: __exit__`

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest version of PyMySQL (0.7.4). It seems like your version doesn't implement the [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) interfaces.

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid, it worked perfectly :)

Comment: @inbinder Python actually compiles down to bytecode and then the bytecode is interpreted, so it is actually correct to say that syntactically invalid Python "doesn't compile."

Answer (score 0):

Try to do some opt before db operation finish :

```
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```